# VSCode breakpoint is not triggering in simple angular 13 app

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

I could use some help finding out what specifically is keeping vscode debug/breakpoints from working in this small angular 13 project:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample02

The README.md has instructions on how to reproduce the issue.
There isn't much code there -- so it's particularly frustrating that such a trivial example isn't working.

So I recreated the project from scratch:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample01

...and lo and behold, debug/breakpoints are working just fine!

The tsconfig.json files are identical:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample01/blob/main/tsconfig.json
https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample02/blob/main/tsconfig.json

and vscode launch.json files are pretty similar:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample01/blob/main/.vscode/launch.json
https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample02/blob/main/.vscode/launch.json

There are a number of small angular version differences inside the package.json files.  The broken one has 13.0-ish dependencies and the working one has 13.1-ish.

Also interesting (and ironic) is that in the working example, we have this in package.json:
https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample01/blob/main/package.json

```
{
  "name": "flat-tree-example-with-debugging",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
```

...and note that '--open' parameter that launches the browser is absent from the last line, yet when I run the browser actually opens, displays the page and then focus moves to vscode and the proper breakpoint.

To contrast, in the broken example package.json:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample02/blob/main/package.json

...I had to add the --open parameter to get the browser to open.  So perhaps this is part of the problem, I sure don't know.

In related news, I spent a lot of time looking at vscode trace output (with a different angular project) looking for issues on my side setting sourceMap to true.  I created a vscode issue on github here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1178 but it didn't go anywhere :-(.

## Followup

Feb 6 / 2:20pm CST.
I just copied the package.json to the broken project and ran "npm install --force".  Didn't help.  The debugging/breakpoints still don't work, and the browser does not launch as it does in the working project.
So this resolved the minor angular version differences mentioned above as well as as insuring both working/broken use  "start": "ng serve", ...and it's debugging/breakpoints still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  kdiff3 pointed out that the broken example was missing .vscode/tasks.json file.  Here is the file from the working version:

https://github.com/eostermueller/angularFlatTreeExample01/blob/main/.vscode/tasks.json

I copied it into place on the broken example and it worked fine!! ....crazy that vscode didn't display any errors complaining about missing/unresolved tasks.  This file was created auto-magically for me in the working example, and I don't remember deleting this in the broken example.

Perhaps older versions of vscode didn't create this?

I created this vscode enhancement request

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1194

...to get an error message when tasks.json is missing or launch.json references some non-existent task.